# Is it possible to set the timezone in browserstack?

Tags: date, browserstack

I found something for the selenium test but I dont see something for manually browsing. It looks like GMT is allways used.

I look for a way to test my local site with a specific timezone. Setting the timezone for the machine would also change the timezone for my local webserver (iis on windows) and thats not what I want.

I know I can set the time offset for firefox but this is also not my preferred way, because it realy sets an offset not a timezone with a different behaviour for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, changing the time zone on BrowserStack 'Live' is unavailable. However, we have made a note of your request and will keep you posted.

Mukesh from BrowserStack

Comment: What about Automated Mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can use browserstack.timezone capabilities. For more information refer https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

Comment: Thats realy for BrowserStack Automate. I need something for when  I manually browse  within browserstack.